# Applying color filter in StateListDrawable not working

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, colorfilter

I'm writing an application in which I have to do some on-the-fly image-mutations.

What I have to do is put a drawable on screen somewhere, give it a fancy color that can be changed on the fly and make it clickable (with a StateListDrawable).

For the color-change on the fly I was thinking to use a PorterDuffColorFilter which I would apply on a drawable. However adding drawables to a StateListDrawable seems to be a bad idea as the color filters get removed.
But then I came up with this solution that I found somewhere on SO:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap one = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable, options);
    Bitmap oneCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(one.getWidth(), one.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(oneCopy);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(onTheFlyColorResId, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    c.drawBitmap(one, 0, 0, p);

    ...

    sld.addState(new int[]{-stateFocused}, new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), oneCopy));
```

This kind of works, but there's one tricky thing. The image below is the result while the R.drawable.my_drawable is a PNG file that entirly black with a 3px transparant border around it.

[image: The problem...]

If I just add the original drawable I do get a full black image with some transparant pixels on the side like below:

```
    sld.addState(new int[]{-stateFocused}, context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable));
```

And this is the result:

[image: The result I want but without the color filter]

So I was thinking that something might be wrong with the oneCopy bitmat or the drawing on the canvas, so I change the code to this:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap one = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable, options);

    ...

    sld.addState(new int[]{-stateFocused}, new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), one));
```

So no more transformations of the drawable, just reading it as a bitmap and transforming it to a drawable again also results in a strange result:

[image: Also not good...]

And what I would simply want is the second image with my custom color applied.

Does anyone has an idea why I get that strange fade-effect left and right of the image?

Answer (score 0):

To apply a color filter and change the color of a drawable I find that using a base drawable which is grayscale/white is best while used in combination with Mode.MULTIPLY PorterDuff filter.

If you want to do it all in code is fine, but the best combination, in my opinion, is to have a TextView defined in XML with the said white-grayscale background then in code you can change the background color:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mybox"
    . . . 
    android:background="@drawable/box"
```

The box drawable can be anything, PNG or another XML defining a rectangular shape filled with solid color white.

```
int onTheFlyColor = 0xAARRGGBB; or getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.mybox);
tv.getBackground().setColorFilter(onTheFlyColor, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: That should indeed work (tested something similar) but my problem is to apply a color filter using a StateListDrawable...

Comment: @dirkvranckaert I think you don't mean to change the color "on the fly" but just to have a different color for each state in the `StateListDrawable`. On the fly would be if the user or some algorithm chooses a color each time a state changes, but if I understand you correctly, the color for each state is known and hardcoded.

Comment: I indeed have a StateListDrawable. If the sld is selected I show a drawable that is 'hardcoded'. in the other case (when not selected so just displayed) I want to display the black drawable but change the color of the black drawable with a color filter to a color that the user can select in the activity before the one where I show the buttons...